# add class to all elements one by one on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to move class on every click from first to last element. On my first click it adds the class to first `<li>` and on second click it moves the class to second `<li>` and remove the class from first one and so on.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('button').on('click', changeClass);

        function changeClass() {
            var ind = $(this).index();
            var i = 0;
            $("li").eq(i).addClass("current").siblings().removeClass("current");
        }
    });
</script>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNyWQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like following using [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method. First set `index` to `0` and get the total number of `li` and on click of the button remove `current` class from all `li` and set `current` class to the `li` at `index`. After that increase the index by `1`. To get back the first `li` after reaching last use `(index+1) % total`.

```js
var index = 0;
var total = $("li").length;

$("button").click(function() {
  $("li").removeClass("current");
  $("li").eq(index).addClass("current"); 
  index = (index+1) % total;
});
```

```css
.current{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>one</li>
</ul>

<button>click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without index.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  var el = $('li.current');

  if(el.length == 0){
     $('ul').find('li').eq(0).addClass('current');//if no current exist
     return;
  }
  $('li.current').removeClass('current');
  if(typeof el.next() !== 'undefined'){
      el.next().addClass('current');
  }
})
```

```css
.current{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>one</li> <!-- initialize with atleast one class current -->
    <li>one</li>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>one</li>
</ul>

<button>click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all find the **next** li with class 'current' as well as remove the class of current li. Then check if length is >0 means element exists otherwise not.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
   var next = $('#main').find('li.current').removeClass('current').next('li');
   if(next.length) { next.addClass('current'); }
   else { $('#main').find('li').first().addClass('current'); }
});

<ul id="main">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li> 
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sbLhewgh/